# Custom NER Training model with SpaCy won't train

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have followed this tutorial in [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJy11kOlgvk)

Here the whole code from my jupyter notebook

```py
import spacy
import fitz
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import random

train_data = pickle.load(open('train_data.pkl', 'rb'))
train_data[0]
```

The output of train_data[0] is shown here

```py
nlp = spacy.blank('en')

def train_model(train_data):
    if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
        nlp.add_pipe(ner, last = True)
        
    for _, annotation in train_data:
        for ent in annotation['entities']:
            ner.add_label(ent[2])
            
            
    
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
        for itn in range(10):
            print('Starting iteration' + str(itn))
            random.shuffle(train_data)
            losses = {}
            index = 0
            # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
            #batches = minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=compounding(4.0, 32.0, 1.001))
            for text, annotations in train_data:
                try:
                
                    nlp.update(
                        [texts],  # batch of texts
                        [annotations],# batch of annotations
                        sgd=optimizer,
                        drop=0.5,  # dropout - make it harder to memorise data
                        losses=losses)
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
            print("Losses", losses)

train_model(train_data)
```

What is weird is the output of the function which is :

Starting iteration0

Losses {}

Starting iteration1

Losses {}

Starting iteration2

Losses {}

Starting iteration3

Losses {}

Starting iteration4

Losses {}

Starting iteration5

Losses {}

Starting iteration6

Losses {}

Starting iteration7

Losses {}

Starting iteration8

Losses {}

Starting iteration9

Losses {}

It seems like there is no data entering the model at all even though I can run train_data and get an output !!

spaCy version    2.3.0
Python version   3.7.3

Comment: How many items do you have in your `train_data`?

Answer (score 0):

for **text**, annotations in train_data:

```
try:
    nlp.update(
        [***texts***],  # batch of texts
        [annotations],# batch of annotations
        sgd=optimizer,
        drop=0.5,  # dropout - make it harder to memorise data
        losses=losses).-----
```

replace **texts** with **text**